# Laravel 5.6 Adding Additonal route files

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.5

Larave 5.6 by default comes with api.php, channels.php, console.php and web.php routing files.  Is it possible to create another routing file e.g. vueroutes.php.  I am using some of the larave's blade views.  But I also have vue routes under assets/js directory.  I developed my vue code on a non production server where I only had the Laravel base install and the vue code with one line in the route web.php.  The clean url's work fine but when I move it to the prod assets directory the # sign starts showing up even though all other code is exactly the same.

```
Route::get('{path}', function () {
return view('welcome');
})->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );
```